# Value of density parameters in CMB time

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I was looking for the value of the  density parameters ($\Omega_{i}$) in cosmology at the time of decoupling (CMB Time).

I know that the Planck Colaboration aproximatelly  gives $\Omega_{m}=0.315$, $\Omega_{\Lambda}=1-\Omega_{m}$. But those are given at the present time.

I know that i can infer them doing some calculations but I prefer to have a measured value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a (precisely) measured value at any epoch, since the deduction of these parameters relies on watching things change with cosmic epoch.

The critical density can be inferred from "local" measurements of the Hubble parameters, but local measurements of the mass density have very large uncertainties. Other inferences (e.g. from primordial nucleosynthesis or the CMB) rely on physical conditions at other epochs, couched in terms of the present-day parameters. The dark energy density cannot be estimated locally afaik, but relies on measurements of the CMB, large scale structure or supernovae at a wide range of redshifts.

The quoted cosmological parameters are just that - in the framework of the $\Lambda$CDM FRW universe, their values at one epoch imply their values at any epoch.

However, it is a very interesting question as to whether various parameters can be quoted with better precision at other epochs than in the present?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I have never seen such data in articles or books etc. However, you can use a cosmological calculator to find the value at $z\approx 1100$