# Can cosmological parameters be quoted more precisely at other epochs?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, cosmological-constant

Inspired by [Value of density parameters in CMB time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529005/value-of-density-parameters-in-cmb-time/529038#529038) it seems to me that when cosmological parameters are quoted (e.g. from the CMB or type Ia supernovae), they are almost exclusively quoted in terms of their present day values, but inferred from things that happened earlier.

But is there any value in quoting their values at other epochs, perhaps more tuned to the phenomena that are being measured? Are the parameters ($\Omega_M$, $\Omega_b$, $\Omega_\Lambda$, $H$) actually known more precisely at an epoch earlier than the present day?

Comment: Sure, $\Omega$ is known to be $1$ at earlier epochs with much greater precision than it is today, just because we know that the universe existed after that for a long time.

Comment: @A.V.S. Yes, I knew that. I was thinking more in terms of $\Omega_M$, $\Omega_{\Lambda}$, $\Omega_b$ and $H$.

Comment: @RobJeffries I dont think so, Since we need measure them in precisly, for each data information we have to use LCDM model and statistics. CMB or BAO or BBN datas are the important ones. I dont think theres much an option other then rely on these datas and statistics